# How to convert diameter of matrix to zero in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix and I want to convert diameter value to zero in python. can you help me?

Matrix:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you meant diagonal, iterate over the list with enumerate, then iterate over the sublist, and check if the indexes are equal (that means you're on the diagonal), and assign zero, else the current value.

```
mydata = [[1,2,3,4],
[5,6,7,8],
[9,10,11,12],
[13,14,15,16]]

for i,l in enumerate(mydata):
    l[i]=0

[0, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 0, 7, 8]   
[9, 10, 0, 12] 
[13, 14, 15, 0]
```

Comment: As OP is using NumPy, this is a needlessly slow and complicated answer. Just use `np.fill_diagonal()`

Comment: oh yeah i suppose you could use that, wasn't sure if he had already used np on the list. what makes you think the source code is so much faster here? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L778-L909

Answer (score 0):

When possible, avoid nested loops.

As you are working with numpy's arrays, you can use

```
np.fill_diagonal(mydata, 0)
```

Comment: OP is using numpy arrays, so you can and should drop the for loop part of your answer.